# MySQL - ORDER BY multiple words, then alphabetically?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I change this part of the query to have multiple words ordered first in sequence, then the rest of the results alphabetically?

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Professional%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END asc, name asc
```

So, it needs to be:

```
'%Professional%' 1
'%Leader%' 2
'%Advocate%' 3
'%Clinician%' 4
'%Educator%' 5
'%Scholar%' 6
```

Then all other results alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just expand your `CASE` expression with each of the desired words:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Professional%' THEN 1
     WHEN name LIKE '%Leader%' THEN 2
     WHEN name LIKE '%Advocate%' THEN 3
     WHEN name LIKE '%Clinician%' THEN 4
     WHEN name LIKE '%Educator%' THEN 5
     WHEN name LIKE '%Scholar%' THEN 6
     ELSE 7
END,
name
```